# Test failing when running in bamboo but passing when running in local

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-remotedriver

My test is failing when executing using remote chrome driver but when executing in chrome it passes.
can i get help on this

i have bamboo plan that is failing and it says unable to locate element and i think remote chrome is the problem here because when running on the browser it works fine

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.